# Use MVC Controls In Webmatrix Web Pages

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I was wondering if anyone had tried and succeeded in integrating third-party mvc controls with Webmatrix Web Pages (Razor).  I own DevExpress, plus I would like to try Telerik MVC controls, so any examples or help in this manner would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Wade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is built on top of Razor (not the other way around). Helpers built in MVC will not work in Web Pages. MVC has more stuff in it that doesn't exist in Web Pages like ModelState.

Comment: That kinda sucks as there are some really nice controls out there that would be nice to use.  Does Microsoft plan on maybe offering a toolkit like it does for Silverlight and AJAX?

Comment: We have the ASP.NET Web Helpers Library (NuGet id = Microsoft.Web.Helpers) that is a mish-mash of helpers.  We'd like to open source it someday as well.  So maybe that is what you're looking for?!?!